# How to get response after dispatch action?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-api-middleware

Is there an option to get back response from **redux-api-middleware** inside this function?

```
dispatch(someAction()).then(() => {
  // CONSOLE.LOG RESPONSE HERE
});
```

Comment: Look into [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) for how to dispatch async actions

Comment: The action is done correctly and I know how to store its result in redux state. The question is how to return the answer to the above function :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with an example from the `redux-api-middleware` [docs](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware/blob/6e782cdea6d5451e6e96406de631db7c11df1a2d/README.md).

```
const USER_REQUEST = '@@user/USER_REQUEST'
const USER_SUCCESS = '@@user/USER_SUCCESS'
const USER_FAILURE = '@@user/USER_FAILURE'

const getUser = () => ({
  [RSAA]: {
    endpoint: 'https://hostname/api/users/',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    types: [
      USER_REQUEST,
      USER_SUCCESS,
      USER_FAILURE
    ]
  }
})
```

If you are using `redux-thunk` you can do the following:

```
dispatch(getUser())
  .then((payload) => {
    console.log(payload, 'oh hai, payload');
  });
```